# How to use getOrinsertfunction method in LLVM after version 8.0

Tags: c++, llvm

I am a freshman to use llvm for instrumenting. And lately when I tried to compile a .pass I noticed that the type of the method **getOrinsertfunction** has changed to  FunctionCallee from Constant(it used to be) in version 11.0.

So this can no longer work because "No viable conversion from 'llvm::FunctionCallee' to 'llvm::Constant *'"

> Constant *beginFun = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("_ly_fun_b",
> type);

Is there any method to make it work?

And here is the method runOnFunction.
Thank you for replying!

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override
{
    printf("------------- runOnFunction --------------\n");
    if (F.getName().startswith("_ly_fun"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    LLVMContext &context = F.getParent()->getContext();
    BasicBlock &bb = F.getEntryBlock();
    Constant *beginFun = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("_ly_fun_b", type);
    Instruction *beginInst = dyn_cast<Instruction>(bb.begin());
    FunctionType *type = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt64Ty(context), {}, false);
    Instruction *beginFun = dyn_cast<Instruction>((F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("_ly_fun_b", type)).getCallee());
    Value *beginTime = nullptr;

    if (Function *fun = dyn_cast<Function>(beginFun))
    {
        CallInst *inst = CallInst::Create(fun);
        inst->insertBefore(beginInst);
        beginTime = inst;
    }

    for (Function::iterator I = F.begin(), E = F.end(); I != E; ++I)
    {
        BasicBlock &BB = *I;
        for (BasicBlock::iterator I = BB.begin(), E = BB.end(); I != E; ++I)
        {
            ReturnInst *IST = dyn_cast<ReturnInst>(I);
            if (IST)
            {
                FunctionType *type = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(context), {Type::getInt8PtrTy(context),Type::getInt64Ty(context)}, false);
                Instruction *s = dyn_cast<Instruction>((BB.getModule()->getOrInsertFunction("_ly_fun_e", type)).getCallee());
                if (Function *fun = dyn_cast<Function>(s))
                {
                    IRBuilder<> builder(&BB);
                    CallInst *inst = CallInst::Create(fun, {builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(BB.getParent()->getName()), beginTime});
                    inst->insertBefore(IST);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just extract the value and cast to Constant:

```
auto Callee = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("_ly_fun_b", type);
auto Fun = dyn_cast<Constant>(Callee.getCallee());
```